# Redirect non-existent files via ErrorDocument 404 directive AND record the referrer?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect non-existent files that people might land on to a specific file (landing.php), but I also want to record a referrer for these 404 situations... so how would I do that?

Right now I have a simple ErrorDocument 404 /landing.php entry in my .htaccess file, but how/where can I actually capture the referrer the user came from when they land on the custom landing page (there will be other, regular visitors coming to the landing.php page so I can't just record all referrers for that page, so is there a way to separate the 404 traffic only?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rely on the referer being available as people and software can easily tweak it. In my experience most people don't do that so it's still worth tracking, just make sure you check if it's set before using.

When you use the ErrorDocument directive like you are, [Apache will set the REDIRECT_STATUS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php#53617) env variable that can be accessed in the $_SERVER array, and will contain the HTTP status code.

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']) && $_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'] == '404') {

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        // Log the referer
    }
}
```

Note: I've seen some people say that this doesn't always work but I haven't been able to find what triggers the environment variable being set.

**Update**

According to the [Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html#configuration) these environment variables are set only if you use a local URL. This means you should give a relative path in your ErrorDocument 404 direcive:

```
Error 404 /landing.php
```

If you put a URL there, an external redirect will occur and the environment variable will not be set **even if the URL uses the same domain as your site**.

It appears you're already doing this correctly, but thought I'd include this for any future users.

Comment: boom! that's exactly what I was looking for... check for 404 and then log the referrer. thank you! (now I know about REDIRECT_STATUS too, I guess)

Answer (score 0):

In your `landing.php` file:

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Then you can do whatever it is you need with the `$referer` var.